# Android PackageInstaller and Debug APKs

Tags: android, packageinstaller

I'm working on an application that will not be released on PlayStore as it is running on proprietary hardware as a Kiosk Device that will be used under a controlled environment, as such I've implemented a system by which it will download updates, verify them and then install them using `PackageInstaller`.

For development purposes it would be handy to use the same system to install debug builds i.e. those that specify `<application android:testOnly="true">` in the application manifest.

The issue is that the installation fails with the result message of `[INSTALL_FAILED_TEST_ONLY: installPackageLI]`.

I realise that it is possible to install such an apk using a switch on the `adb install` command, but I would like to know if the same is possible using `PackageInstaller` or if not with `PackageInstaller` directly then by changing some system setting?